# Concatenate Sharepoint Data using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, concatenate

I have some data in a Sharepoint list, but I want to combine the information from different rows into one row. I'm very low code. I know how to use Power Automate, but I can't figure out how to use it to concatenate the information from two rows into one row. Can anyone help me?

For example:
**First Last Rating**

1. John    Smith  Perfect
2. John    Smith  Very Good
3. John    Smith  Good
4. John    Smith  Perfect

All of the rows pertain to John Smith. I want one row that lists the name and all of the ratings.
John   Smith   Perfect, Very Good, Good, Perfect

I don't care how the combined ratings are handled --separated by commas or whatever-- I just want them all together.

PLEASE HELP! I need to be able to do this for work and I am desperate. I have been assigned this task even though I am not an IT or web development specialist. Now my job depends on it.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or need clarification on the solution that I've posted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in MS Flow (Power Automate). Please follow along the solution below.

**SharePoint Online List Data**

[image]

The **Final Output** from MS Flow in **[Compose]** action

[image]

### See the MS Flow Screenshots below

### The Entire Flow

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]

### Detail 3

[image]

### Detail 3-1

[image]

### Detail 3-2

[image]

### Detail 4 and 5

[image]