# Combining several multi select columns in a sharepoint online library using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, multi-select

I have a SharePoint online library, where I want to merge several columns into a single column. Most of the columns are multi select columns (choice/checkbox). How can I use power automate to collect the values that someone selects per column and then have power automate put the selections into a single column? I am not a programmer. I am a technical writer who is attempting to understand all of this.

I find this post: [Concatenate Sharepoint Data using Power Automate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285448/concatenate-sharepoint-data-using-power-automate#)  interesting, but I do not fully understand what is happening.

I do want to know how to combine multiple columns (some multi select) in a SharePoint online library.

Can anyone help? Is there a video on YouTube.com?

Comment: Looks like you've referred to my Power Automate post. However, would like to inform that this can also be done using SharePoint **Calculated** column in depending on your requirements. If it's not complex logic then I would go with Calculated column. If you could elaborate your SharePoint list columns with sample values and the expected results, surely someone would be able to help.

Comment: @Matiur Rahman  I tried using Calculated columns, but SharePoint only shows column choices that are drop-down or single line of text. It does not list multi-select columns. I'm not sure where I can post an example of my columns. Let me try to start a fresh post.

Comment: @MatiurRahman  Here is the new post:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290180/concatenate-sharepoint-library-columns-with-multi-select-options-into-a-single-c

If you can assist, I would be grateful.